# Exception while completing parallel multi instance subprocess: java.util.NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, camunda, camunda-modeler

I am using Camunda BPMN Engine version 7.17.6-ee and Camunda Modeler version 4.6.0

I have a Camunda process which has a parallel multi instance subprocess which has two tasks A and B, where B is a sequential multi instance called activity (T in the figure denotes the transaction Boundaries). When the subprocess is finished, it continues in a loop to get the next open bookings until there are no open bookings left.

[image: Screenshot of the process]

If I run this process, I encounter the following error in the subprocess (more precisely in the sequential multi instance Task B):

```
ERROR [org.camunda.bpm.engine.context] (pool-15-thread-13) ENGINE-16004 Exception while closing command context: null: java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:1000)
at org.camunda.bpm.camunda-engine@7.17.0//org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.MultiInstanceActivityBehavior.getElementAtIndex(MultiInstanceActivityBehavior.java:129)
at org.camunda.bpm.camunda-engine@7.17.0//org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.MultiInstanceActivityBehavior.evaluateCollectionVariable(MultiInstanceActivityBehavior.java:93)
at org.camunda.bpm.camunda-engine@7.17.0//org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.MultiInstanceActivityBehavior.performInstance(MultiInstanceActivityBehavior.java:78)
at org.camunda.bpm.camunda-engine@7.17.0//org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.SequentialMultiInstanceActivityBehavior.complete(SequentialMultiInstanceActivityBehavior.java:58)
at org.camunda.bpm.camunda-engine@7.17.0//org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.operation.PvmAtomicOperationActivityEnd.execute(PvmAtomicOperationActivityEnd.java:105)
at org.camunda.bpm.camunda-engine@7.17.0//org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.operation.PvmAtomicOperationActivityEnd.execute(PvmAtomicOperationActivityEnd.java:35)
at org.camunda.bpm.camunda-engine@7.17.0//org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.AtomicOperationInvocation.execute(AtomicOperationInvocation.java:99)
at org.camunda.bpm.camunda-engine@7.17.0//org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.invokeNext(CommandInvocationContext.java:131)
at org.camunda.bpm.camunda-engine@7.17.0//org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.performNext(CommandInvocationContext.java:111)
at org.camunda.bpm.camunda-engine@7.17.0//org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.performOperation(CommandInvocationContext.java:86)
at org.camunda.bpm.camunda-engine@7.17.0//org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:623)
at org.camunda.bpm.camunda-engine@7.17.0//org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:597)
at org.camunda.bpm.camunda-engine@7.17.0//org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.operation.PvmAtomicOperationActivityNotifyListenerEnd$1.callback(PvmAtomicOperationActivityNotifyListenerEnd.java:47)
at org.camunda.bpm.camunda-engine@7.17.0//org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.operation.PvmAtomicOperationActivityNotifyListenerEnd$1.callback(PvmAtomicOperationActivityNotifyListenerEnd.java:41)
at org.camunda.bpm.camunda-engine@7.17.0//org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.PvmExecutionImpl.continueExecutionIfNotCanceled(PvmExecutionImpl.java:2078)
at org.camunda.bpm.camunda-engine@7.17.0//org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.PvmExecutionImpl.dispatchDelayedEventsAndPerformOperation(PvmExecutionImpl.java:2027)
at org.camunda.bpm.camunda-engine@7.17.0//org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.operation.PvmAtomicOperationActivityNotifyListenerEnd.eventNotificationsCompleted(PvmAtomicOperationActivityNotifyListenerEnd.java:41)
at org.camunda.bpm.camunda-engine@7.17.0//org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.operation.PvmAtomicOperationActivityNotifyListenerEnd.eventNotificationsCompleted(PvmAtomicOperationActivityNotifyListenerEnd.java:27)
at org.camunda.bpm.camunda-engine@7.17.0//org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.core.operation.AbstractEventAtomicOperation.execute(AbstractEventAtomicOperation.java:66)
...
```

The exception occurs in Camunda in this class `MultiInstanceActivityBehavior` and in this method:

```
  protected Object getElementAtIndex(int i, Collection<?> collection) {
     Object value = null;
     int index = 0;
     Iterator<?> it = collection.iterator();
     while (index <= i) {
      value = it.next();
      index++;
     }
    return value;
 }
```

`it.next()` throws the exception.

My suspicion was that the list was being manipulated in parallel by another thread and that's why there is an exception, but apparently I'm wrong because I tried thread safe collections and had no success.

Can someone help me and tell me what I am doing wrong or what is wrong with the process?

Answer (score 0):

I agree that the list likely changed during the execution. Suggest you set a breakpoint in `getElementAtIndex(int i, Collection<?> collection)` and check with each iteration what the index and collection looks like.
As a user of the enterprise edition (-ee) you could also get assistance form Camunda support via https://jira.camunda.com

Comment: I have already debugged but when I debug it, the error strangely does not occur. I will try with Camunda support thanks.